# swift add switch programmatically in side menu

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, addition, uiswitch

Im trying to style my side menu, I want the `UISwitch` to edit the label next to it. But the only think that happens when I click on the switch is that the app crashes and I receives following error message

> 2016-08-20 01:56:20.545 Moppio[4342:8394913] -[Moppio.BackTableViewController test()]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe66a4ba530
>   2016-08-20 01:56:20.554 Moppio[4342:8394913] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Moppio.BackTableViewController test()]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe66a4ba530'
>   *** First throw call stack: ...

And this is the `code` that I use right now.

```
        //Profile picture + bar
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 60))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.40, green:0.40, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)

    let profileImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 5, 50, 50)) // Change frame size according to you...
    profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "profile.png") //Image set your
    view.addSubview(profileImageView)

    let LabelStatus = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
    LabelStatus.center = CGPointMake(120, 32)
    LabelStatus.textColor = UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.95, blue:0.95, alpha:1.0)
    LabelStatus.font = UIFont(name: "BebasNeue", size: 24)
    LabelStatus.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(LabelStatus)

    let switchStatus=UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(195, 15, 20, 20))

    func test() {
    if (switchStatus.on == true){
        LabelStatus.text = ("Available")
        print("on")
    }
    if (switchStatus.on == false){
        LabelStatus.text = ("Not available")
        LabelStatus.center = CGPointMake(130, 32)
        print("off")
    }
    }

    switchStatus.on = true
    switchStatus.setOn(true, animated: false);
    switchStatus.addTarget(self, action: "test()", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    switchStatus.onTintColor = UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.95, blue:0.95, alpha:1.0)
    switchStatus.thumbTintColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.25, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0)
    self.view.addSubview(switchStatus);

    return view
}
```

And this is what it currently looks [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgxpg.png).

**How can I make the switch edit the label next to it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the 'unrecognized selector' error because you are incorrectly targeting the `test` function.

In this line

```
switchStatus.addTarget(self, action: "test()", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

You are trying to find a function `test` on `self`, but `test` is a function within the table view's `viewForHeaderInSection` function, not a function on `self`.

Additionally, the selector syntax has changed from a String to the new `#selector` syntax.

To fix this, move the `test` function to be a function on `self`. You will also need to be able to reference your `switchStatus` and `LabelStatus` objects, so you could move these to be declared as members of your view controller as well.

So at the end you should end up with something like this:

```
class BackTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let LabelStatus = UILabel()
    let switchStatus = UISwitch()

    func test() {
        // update the label here
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
        // ...
        switchStatus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BackTableViewController.test), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that line of code, your syntax for the selector is not correct:

```
switchStatus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BackTableViewController.test), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```